Passing an array parameter with pointer to derived classes in C++
What would be the easiest way of passing an array parameter with pointer to derived classes to a function?
Let's say I have a base class called ResourceTransferE, and a derived class called ResourceTransferE_Upload:
class ResourceTransferE
{};

class ResourceTransferE_Upload : public ResourceTransferE
{};

And I have 2 methods to call, like this:
bool Dispatch(size_t totalTransfers, ResourceTransferE** transfers, bool waitForFinish = false);
bool Dispatch(ResourceTransferE* transfer, bool waitForFinish = false);

If I send only one derived object, the compiler does not complain:
ResourceTransferE_Upload uploadX = ResourceTransferE_Upload::Create(true);
Dispatch(uploadX); //this is ok

However, if I want to dispatch multiple uploads, like this:
ResourceTransferE_Upload* uploads[] = { ResourceTransferE_Upload::Create(true),
    ResourceTransferE_Upload::Create(true) };
Dispatch(sizeof(uploads) / sizeof(void*), &uploads[0]);//this is not ok

The compiler can not figure out which Dispatch() method I am suppose to refer to. I get an error:

no overloaded function could convert all the argument types

What could be the easiest way to get around this problem (assuming I don't want to define my array with base class like ResourceTransferE* uploads[])? Could this be achieved by templates?

maybe i should be more clear, i know you can reinterpret cast it such: Dispatch(sizeof(uploads) / sizeof(void*), reinterpret_cast<ResourceTransferE**>(&uploads[0]), true); , but i was wondering if there is more elegant solution to this?

Define uploads this way: ResourceTransferE* uploads[].

Do not post code that does not work. For example  ResourceTransferE does not have Create in it so calling it elsewhere is confusing.

The problem here is that you are trying to bypass the type system, it is preventing you from putting a ResourceTransferE* in a ResourceTransferE_Upload* array, as pointed above you need to declare it as ResourceTransferE* buffer to begin with, otherwise the type system won't accept your code, which is why you need to do reinterpret_cast to throw the type system out of the window.

Side notes on design : ResourceTransferE** transfers double pointers should almost never be necessary in current C++, Have a look at std::vector for your "resizable array" and maybe you can use sd::vector<std::shared_ptr> . You also seem to be missing a virtual function in the baseclass because it should almost never be needed to cast to a derived class.

classes are polymorphic, there is virtual keyword in my project, i just simplified them when i was posting it

On a side note: sizeof(uploads) / sizeof(void*) can be simplified to std::size(uploads) since uploads is a fixed array. And &uploads[0] can be just uploads since a fixed array decays into a pointer to its 1st element.

As you noticed, you cannot cast ResourceTransferE_Upload** to ResourceTransferE** for a good reason. However, you don't need to. Just create an array of pointers to base, initialize them with pointers to derived instances, and then pass it to function. Simplified:
class ResourceTransferE
{
public:
    virtual ~ResourceTransferE() = default;
};
class ResourceTransferE_Upload : public ResourceTransferE
{};

bool Dispatch(size_t , ResourceTransferE**) {
    return true;
}

int main() {
    ResourceTransferE_Upload up1;
    ResourceTransferE_Upload up2;
    ResourceTransferE* uploads[] = { &up1, &up2 };
    Dispatch(2, uploads);
}

Note that most likely you will need to make the base class polymorphic, so define a virtual destructor.

I came up with a solution like this:
template<typename T>
bool Dispatch(size_t totalTransfers, T** transfers, bool waitForFinish = false)
{
    return Dispatch(totalTransfers, reinterpret_cast<ResourceTransferE**>(&transfers[0]), waitForFinish );
}

However, there might be a more elegant answer.

EDIT:
I added type assuring line after Ahmed AEK suggested:
template<typename T>
bool Dispatch(size_t totalTransfers, T** transfers, bool waitForFinish = false)
{
    static_assert(std::derived_from<T, ResourceTransferE> == true);
    return Dispatch(totalTransfers, reinterpret_cast<ResourceTransferE**>(&transfers[0]), waitForFinish );
}


You might want to restrict T to being derived from ResourceTransferE (using enable_if or constraints), otherwise you have thrown the type system out of the window.

On a side note: &transfers[0] can be just transfers
